# Add annotations for specific PDF pages using the command line

Tags: command-line, pdf, python, ghostscript, pdftk

I have a PDF with 5 pages, and would like to add the annotations `note 3` and `note 4` at pages 3 and 4; where or how the annotations are styled doesn't matter. It should be an FOSS based solution.

Comment: You may find more success if you post your question on the Software Recommendations SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  Before posting there, read the community's posting requirements, such as specifying an OS and price.

Comment: Thx! How is it not a superuser question though? In the original question, I had more specific details on what could be accepted as an answer but someone closed it; now I am getting redirected out again.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Unfortunately, there are a few people on this site who choose to close questions in a rather draconian manner, with little to no explanation given as to why.  It certainly comes off like a power trip or simply not interested in considering the experience of other people, like yourself. You can try separating your question into 2: (1) asking much of the things you deleted, but removing anything referring to a software recommendation, and (2) a question of Software Recommendations SE (where we work to be much more considerate) specifically asking for a software recommendation.

Comment: I am absolutely not interested in software recommendation though; I have a problem that needs a solution. I do not use proprietary software so if a solution requires, say Adobe software, then I won't accept it. Anything else goes. The software I listed (pdftk, qpdf etc.) are what I found so far; the answer doesn't need to use them at all, or compare them.

Comment: I see.  I think maybe where you write *"It should be an [sic] FOSS based solution"* is possibly confusing people.  I see many, many questions inappropriately closed on this site, as well as people bragging about how many questions they have closed.  My participation in this site has decreased significantly as a result.

Comment: I just noticed that your question was closed by a moderator.  How about you ask him why he closed it?

Comment: I flagged for mod attention and got no response since two weeks.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, where certain people pride themselves on quickly closing questions without leaving any helpful comments.  I'm sorry for your experience here, as I know it is not pleasant or helpful to have that happen to you.